# PyQT5, QT,Python, Cycle to create QLabel

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, cycle, qlabel

How do I realize the cycle to create a QLabel? I'm making my first GUI program - Individual Diet. I want to create a function that gives an opportunity for user to add new recipe. From 1 label I need to get the value of calories.

```
self.labelcal = QLabel(self.recipe)
self.labelcal.setGeometry(QRect(240, 67, 47, 13))
self.labelcal.setText(self.valuecaltext)
```

Here is how I add the label to the screen, but every time I add one more recipe, value of calories in first label changes on last value. So, I need to create some kind of cycle like `self.labecal[i]`, but this is not working, my not cycle but I need after this call this value in:

```
self.valcal = self.labecal.text()
self.valcal = int(self.labelcal)
self.valueinbar = self.ui.progressBarCal.value()
self.valueinbar = int(self.valueinbar)
self.valbarcal = self.valuecaltext + self.valueinbar
self.ui.progressBarCal.setValue(self.valbarcal)
```

Comment: All capital nicks look bad on the first spot. I suggest to become simply "Zaza Zazarenko".

Comment: Is there are reason to manually set the label's geometry instead of using a layout? Also the "cycle" thing you keep talking about - is this just an attempt to add multiple lables in a loop? If so, please provide more code where you show how you do it and not just write "like `self.labecal[i]`". If you need to handle multiple signals of a set of same UI components consider using the `QSignalMapper` (see [example](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Using%20a%20signal%20mapper)).